# How to make onedrive works more like dropbox

Tags: dropbox, onedrive

I have a file. I want to know the location of the file. I copy the path to clipboard and this is what I get

https://d.docs.live.net/673b7e884bddbb59/domainbanned.xlsx

Okay. First of all, I want to know the location of the file in my computer. I am not interested in the location of the file in onedrive.

Also everytime I save a file, onedrive would automatically upload the file to server. I am not interested on that feature. Just save the damn file and synchronize in background.

Also I often got message that some files fail to upload and I had no idea.

Enough is enough.

This whole synchronization between office and onedrive drives me insane.

How can I turn that off?

Comment: So you’re referring to Office, right? You should make that clear. Because Office doesn’t rely on an external OneDrive client, it never does anything on-disk. It also doesn’t know whether you have a OneDrive client installed. If you don’t want to use the Office-internal client, simply save to disk...?

Comment: I am saving to disk. The folder is synchronized to one drive.

Answer (score 1):

You save your document using "Save As" and save it to the local drive. If it happens to be in the OneDrive folder, it will upload after you save it locally. You are editing a remote file currently which is why it is taking longer to save the document. Rather than saving it locally, you are always saving it remotely. The issue with saving a document as Save As (if you are not the source owner of the file) is that you have two copies. You'll eventually have to merge the two different versions or figure out who will be the sole owner of the file and to give the other person read/write access via OneDrive.

Comment: if I open a local copy, office will actually open the server copy. How can I specify that I really want to open a local copy?